# TCL HTTP set up headers to send post request

Tags: rest, http, tcl

I am totally new to tcl.

I am trying to send a post request to a server. Those are the headers I am trying to send :

```
"POST test HTTP/1.1"
"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
"keep-alive:true"
"Authorization: Basic khjkjkhkhkfzxc"
"client: amin"
"Content-Length:10"
"ggggsis"
```

My code is :

```
set bs "Basic khjkjkhkhkfzxc"
set hd [list Authorization $bs]
set tk[http::geturl $url  -headers $hd]

set res [http::data $tk]
http::cleanup $tk

return $tk
```

Why doesn't this work? Where is my mistake? And how to fix it?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**: I created a small server socket to display my request and here is my new code for post:

```
set bs "Basic gfhfghfdhgf"
    set hd [list Authorization $bs]
    set token [http::geturl $url  -headers $hd -query [::http::formatQuery blabla blablo] -type "text/xml"]
    puts "done"
    set postStat [http::status $token]
    set postResp [http::data $token]
    puts $postResp
    puts "ok"
    puts $postStat
```

Here is what it is being displayed

```
Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1 at Fri Aug  1 10:51:22 EDT 2014
POST /QUEUE/test HTTP/1.0
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: Tcl http client package 2.5.0
Authorization: Basic ZGVmYXVsdCJkZWZhdWx0
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 13
```

The problem is that the program send the post but is doesn't move out from 
`set token [http::geturl $url  -headers $hd -query [::http::formatQuery blabla blablo] -type "text/xml"],`

And the httpget query is never being sent ("done" is never being printed and the content of the query doesn't print in the server side)

Sorry for if I explain things badly.

Thanks

Comment: There is a space between `tk` and the left bracket in the third line, right? Apart from the fact that you shouldn't call `cleanup` on the token before you return it (`cleanup` destroys all the information in the token) nothing seems very wrong. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: it seems that it doesn't make any post request. can you please show me how to build the headers on the top with tcl . thanks

Comment: To make a POST request, you need to provide a `-query` option. Look it up in the documentation.

Comment: I'm unable to help you at the moment, hopefully someone else will provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather simpler to build the headers you want to send as a dictionary:

```
dict set hdr Authorization "Basic [binary encode base64 ${user}:${pass}]"
dict set hdr Client amin
```

The other headers you talk about are either correct by default (the content type) or are best left to the http library to handle.

Once you've got the headers *and the data*, you send the `POST` like this:

```
set token [http::geturl $theurl -headers $hdr -query $body]
set responseBody [http::data $token]
# Access headers here...
http::cleanup $token
# The token is no longer valid here
```

Note that you can only access the results of the query until the [`http::cleanup`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm#M43) command is called on it. After that, the results are gone (unless you stored them in a variable elsewhere, of course).

You'd better make sure that the `$body` is formatted right. The [`http::formatQuery`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm#M33) command is designed for this:

```
set body [http::formatQuery fredKey fredValue daveKey daveValue foo bar]
```

Comment: i tried your code and i got a compiling error bad option "encode": must be format or scan
    while executing
"binary encode base64 ${user}:${pass}"

Comment: This could be a version problem: the `encode` / `decode` options were added in Tcl 8.6 back in 2008.